# how to split an input xml after transforming into multiple xml's using one xslt to implement component linking in tridion

Tags: xslt, tridion

suppose input xml is as shown

```
        <Content>
             <ab>xxxx</ab>
             <bc>yyyyyy</bc>
             <ca>uuuuuuu</ca>
         </Content>
```

after transformation the output xml file is

```
          <Content>
             <aaa>xxxx</aaa>
             <bbb>yyyyyy</bbb>
             <ccc>uuuuuuu</ccc>
           </Content>
```

but I want input xml file  to be transformed into a source of tridion component such that the resultant file should look like a component having multiple component links as below
output xml:

```
      <Content>
   <A  xlink:href="/webdavURL/message/aaa.xml" ></A>
   <B xlink:href="/webdavURL/message/bbb.xml" ></B>
   <C  xlink:href="/webdavURL/message/ccc.xml" ></C>
      <Content>
```

where A,B,C are the separate components that are already created from the files that are formed by splitting up the transformed input xml file into multilple xml files.

componenty A's source: file name should be the transformed tag name like aaa.xml

```
        <Content>
       <aaa>xxxx</aaa>
        </Content>
```

here 'aaa' is the tagname for the respective 'ab' tag that is transformed from input xml.

componenty B's source:file name should be the transformed tag name like bbb.xml

```
        <Content>
       <bbb>yyyyyy</bbb>
        </Content>
```

here 'bbb' is the tagname for the respective 'bc' tag that is transformed from input xml.

component C's source:file name should be the transformed tag name like ccc.xml

```
        <Content>
       <ccc>uuuuuuu</ccc>
        </Content>
```

here 'ccc' is the tagname for the respective 'ca' tag that is transformed from input xml.

So I need only single XSLT which converts input xml to tridion component link format and also split each tag in input xml transform it and store it under respective file with file name as transformed tag name.Can somebody help me out.

Comment: I don't see how it is even possible to have a single XSLT that would also save all of the Components separately too. You'll need some glue to tie it all together. 

I don't understand the reasoning behind the requirement that it should be a single XSLT either...

Comment: Ok. Can we have a single xslt  just to transform the input xml into component linking source format and split the tags that are transformed into seperate files. I don't need to create components for that splitted files, i will just transform the tags that are splitted as files according to the source format of how component resides in tridion and load it using Webdav.I think it will solve our problem.

Comment: You appear to have made a design that you can't implement. Perhaps it would be better to write your question in terms of the problem you are trying to solve. That way - the answer is likely to help both you and others.

Comment: Could you please explain your use case on what you're trying to achieve. There could be simple solution/approach possible compare to current approach you have taken. Are you trying to import content using webdav via copy and pasting xml files? As you see the comments from others, seems like you may be complicating your design.

Comment: THis can be done easily using XSLT 2.0 or in XSLT 1.0 one can use an EXSLT implementation that does `<exsl:document>`. Are you interested in such solutions?

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev: can you please explain how to do it in XSLT 1.0 because i'm unable to configure xslt 2.0 in my VS2010 professional, and in XSLT 1.0 version i didnt find any tag called <exsl:document> tag, how can i configure it in VS2010

Comment: @Jeevan: http://mvpxml.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=EXSLT.NET

Comment: @all: I have a xml file whichhave some tags with widgets in it. I want these widget tags transformed into a simple xml element and all these transformed widget tags are to be resided in seperate xmls in tridion system and the input xml should be transformed to be a tridion component link format wherever we find these wiget tags.Is it possible?.

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation seems to be completely reinventing the wheel - is there a reason you can not use the standard component linking features offered by SDL Tridion? Assuming you have 3 target component with the following URIs:

1. Target A (tcm:1-1)
2. Target B (tcm:1-2)
3. Target C (tcm:1-3)

And you have some source Component XML, in either an RTF field with links to the 3 items or 3 seperate Component Link fields, you will have XML source similar to this:

```
<Content>
    <aaa xlink:href="tcm:1-1" xlink:title="Target A">Some text</aaa>
    <bbb xlink:href="tcm:1-2" xlink:title="Target B">Some text</bbb>
    <ccc xlink:href="tcm:1-3" xlink:title="Target C">Some text</ccc>
</Content>
```

Then all your XSLT needs to do is transform the Source XML using a nXSLT Mediatorto the following:

```
<body>
    <a tridion:href="tcm:1-1" title="Target A">Some text</a>
    <a tridion:href="tcm:1-2" title="Target B">Some text</a>
    <a tridion:href="tcm:1-3" title="Target C">Some text</a>
</body>
```

Then apply the Default TBB to turn these links into Dynamic Linking references, and when the page is loaded, the links will get resolved to the paths you want.

If that does not help, please consider re-writing your question so that we can understand what you are actually trying to achieve.